# Make an outlook rule for appointment invitations

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, rules

Is it possible to make an outlook rule that moves any calendar appointments I receive to a certain folder?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I tested this myself in Outlook 2010.

1. Create a new rule for when a message arrives.
2. Under the Step 1 on the conditions page, select `uses the form name form`
3. Under Step 2 on the conditions page, click `form name`
4. Choose Application Forms rather than Personal Forms, and then choose the forms that apply.
   Definitely select the Meeting Request form, and you also may wish to consider:

   - Accept Meeting Response
   - Appointment
   - Decline Meeting Response
   - Meeting Cancellation
   - Tentative Meeting Response
5. On the next page of the wizard, select `move it to the specified folder`, and in Step 2, choose the folder.
6. Finish the wizard

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I use this to forward Meeting Requests to a to-do list app (Todoist) so that I can keep track of everything in one place.

Comment: Is there a way to decline without sending a response?

Answer (score 0):

For Outlook for web (and the new desktop Outlook), you need to add a "Type" condition for when an email has the type "Invitation".

[image]